# TitledBorder for QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel

I'm new here and german, so excuse me for my english^^

I'm now working on a C++ Project with Qt-library 4.7 for university and I want to add some QLabels to a QGridLayout.
In Java it's possible to set a TitledBorder to a JLabel to get a title for a JLabel.

Is there a way to add some kind of TitledBorder to a QLabel?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Well I searched a bit in the Qt overview of QLabel but found nothing.
I want something like:

QLabel *aktBox = new QLabel("Content");
aktBox->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black;") // Maybe here a way to add title

Comment: YEAH! That's what i searched. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @DennisKonoppa The proper procedure is then to Check the question as answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is. Use a QGroupBox.

This is the appearance

[image] [image][image]

From https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qgroupbox.html